# Ctrl-V on Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, spreadsheet, copy-paste

Why is that if i have a jTable set to SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, and I copy 5 cells in a column, I am not able to paste those 5 cells to a different column (but i can paste them in excel)?

Any helpful hints on how to enable this would also be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you have look at Drag and Drop
- you can copy and paste String value from/to JTextComponents saved in the  System clipboard
- JTable can take only whole row
- you can paste value to the single JTable cell which is in the edit mode

Comment: Thanks. I've opted for the System Clipboard.  But why is it that this would not be allowed in the first place?

Comment: @Tai `But why is it that this would not be allowed in the first place?`, sorry I really don't know why, but I think that shoud be the same for MsExcel e.g. you can drag and drop only the row(s) to the MS Access, too, or edit single cell in the edit mode, became from Windows OS